# Windows authentication for a specific user in Blazor Server app

Tags: blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

In ASP.Net Web Forms, you could add the `<allow users...>` and `<deny users...>` tags in web.config to control access to your website.

I'm building a Blazor server side app in .Net 6.0, hosted in IIS, that uses windows authentication. I would like to allow only certain domain users to access the site, but it looks like Blazor doesn't support those web.config tags.

I'm assuming `appsettings.json` would be the place to hold that information. I can create a custom sub-section with a list of users that I could validate in code, but is there a standard/better way? I've read about a `security` sub-section in appsettings, but not sure how to use that for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A policy would do the trick - we had a similar need recently.

Here's an example by just tweaking the AddAuthorization call for just one specific user:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SpecificUserPolicy", policy =>
           policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                      context.User.Identity?.Name?.Equals("AD\\myuser", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false));

    options.DefaultPolicy = options.GetPolicy("SpecificUserPolicy");

    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

You could build on that and implement further checks/config.

Comment: I will investigate this policy approach, it makes sense. Thanks very much!